# I am not able to run angular application

Tags: angularjs

Error : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/api/products' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
:8080/api/products:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Even after adding these in server.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");   
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 :simply use app.use(cors()) .

Solution 2 : app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
next();
});

Answer (score 1):

The problem on the client may be due to the behavior of Browser opting to handle pre-flight CORS. OPTIONS method is used Instead of using GET method. Adding handler for handling OPTIONS is suggested. Here's the code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE, OPTIONS');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Language, Origin, User-Agent');
     if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.sendStatus(204);
     } else {
       next();
     }
});
```

If you are using Angular CLI you may need to enable proxy by adding proxy.conf.json file in angular application root folder with this configuration:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

While running Angular App include --proxy-config as below or more appropriately edit pacakage.json start script to include the configuration:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Here is good article on [setting up proxy call](https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)